# SoundCloud oEmbed requests for public sets forbidden

Tags: soundcloud

I am getting "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" returned when making CURL requests via soundcloud.com/oembed for SoundCloud sets URLs despite them being set to public. Individual tracks work fine including those belonging to a set.

This seems to be a recent issue as some of the sets I've been testing were working up until a few weeks ago.

Example curl request via command line that is forbidden despite being public:

$ curl -v "http://soundcloud.com/oembed" -d 'format=json' -d 'url=https://soundcloud.com/edsheeran/sets/bloodstream' -L -v -s -o /dev/null

If you do the same for one of the tracks in this set (eg soundcloud.com/rudimentaluk/bloodstream) then you get a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" header response.

Comment: Are you still geting 403s for this? If I try to do it for `https://soundcloud.com/rudimentaluk/bloodstream`, then it works for me.

Comment: Also now working for me! Thanks for letting me know. I've also tested a bunch of other sets that had also stopped working via this method and the also work. So assume was some glitch on SoundCloud end?